# Reading data from Serial input to CSV file in Python

Tags: python, pyserial

I working on creating a datalogging system for an array of PV panels.  Two of my desired measurables are voltage and current which I am measuring from the following device.
http://www.westmountainradio.com/pdf/PWRcheckManual.pdf

My goal is read in the values outputted serially from the PWRcheck device, formatted into a .csv file, and store on a raspberry pi.

Currently, I have pieced together the following code which can read the data to a .xml file.  My end goal is to read in the serial input from the device, then write the data to a .csv file with mV in one column and mA in a second column.

The issue I am running into is that way the serial output from the PWRcheck device is formatted. I have been unable to write this data to any file except a .xml file.

```
numoflines=0
f = open("test.xml","wb")
while numoflines<2:
    db = ser.readline()
    numoflines = numoflines+1
    ser.flushInput()

while True:
    try:
        data = ser.readline()
        print(db)
        f.write(db)
        f.flush()
    except(KeyboardInterrupt):
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        break
```

Data from the PWRcheck device is printed in the following way format.

```
6027,13
6027,13
6026,13
6024,13
6028,13
6024,13
6028,13
6027,12
6031,12
6027,13
6027,13
6028,13
6027,13
```

I have tried using the split function but have been receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

It seems that each line is written as a single string which I have been unable to parse. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first while loop is there to ignore some lines from the the device that I do not want.

Comment: use `f.write(db.encode())`